# Obtener valores dentro de un ArrayList<String[]> por posiciones

Tags: java

Tengo un ArrayList<String[]> array = service.getInformacion(); con los datos que se encuentran en la imagen la verdad no se como recorrer estos datos ya que tiene una posición[0] y dentro de esa tiene varias posiciones0[2] con valores y no se como obtenerlos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
ArrayList<String[]> array = service.getAlldescargas();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(array.get(i).toString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes realizarlo de esta forma obteniendo el array e iterando para obtener sus elementos dentro de cada elemento del `ArrayList` :

```
   ArrayList<String[]> array = service.getAlldescargas();

   for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {

        for(int j=0; j < array.get(i).length; j++){
            System.out.println(array.get(i)[j]);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Me sirvió super bien muchas gracias.

Comment: Excelente @Angelita saludos.